# django multiwidget decompress value is None

Tags: python, django

I am subclassing Django's MultiWidget class and running into an issue in the decompress method. The decompress method is being called, however 'value' is always None even though there is definitely data in the database for this field. I even tried overriding the render method and value is None here as well. The issue is that value should be non-Null when decompress is called, but instead it is None. I am using MultiWidget in conjunction with a subclass of MultiValueField. Here is the code:

**forms.py:**

```
class MyMultiWidget(forms.widgets.MultiWidget):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        self.attrs = attrs
        widgets = (
            TextInput(),
            TextInput(),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
            CheckboxInput(attrs={'value': False}),
        )
        super(MyMultiWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):   # decompress stored database format to HTML form format
        print('decompress called')
        print("this is my value: " + str(value))
        if value:
            dict_value = json.loads(value)
            return dict_value
        return ""

#===============================================================

class MyMultiField(forms.fields.MultiValueField):
    widget = MyMultiWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            forms.CharField(),
            forms.CharField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
            forms.BooleanField(),
        )
        super(MyMultiField, self).__init__(fields=fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, values):
        print('my values: ' + str(values))
        return json.dumps(values)

#===============================================================

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_tag = False
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
            )
            super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    my_multi_field = MyMultiField(required=False, widget=MyMultiWidget())
```

If anyone could tell my why I am seeing None for the value argument in decompress, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell you why you are seeing None but I can tell you what you are doing wrong. Storing CSV in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what I was doing wrong. As it turns out, the issue had nothing to do with the `MultiValueField` or `MultiWidget` to after all, but rather a careless typo on my part. The issue was in my views.py file in my update view function when I was fetching the model instance from the database. I was doing:

`MyModel(pk=my_id)`

When I should have been doing:

`MyModel.objects.get(pk=my_id)`

So I wasn't even getting an instance of the model at all. Needless to say I feel pretty dumb right now ;) but Im glad its fixed. Hopefully this helps someone else out somehow!